# Mysql group by get value base of another colum value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have one long query return like below table

```
item_Id    name            value priority
1        department         A      F
1        department         B      T
1        zone               12     F
1        area             Africa   F
2        department         A      F
2        zone               12     F
2        area              Africa  F
2        area              Europe  T
```

Could I use group by to achieve below result

```
item_id   name            value
 1       department       B
 1       zone             12
 1       area            Africa
 2       department        A
 2       zone             12
 2       area             Europe
```

Basically, i would like to to group `name` , and the value is based on priority without join the query itself

Comment: What does T and F denotes in priority column?

Comment: it is true/false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number()

```
select * from
(
select item_id, name, value,
  row_number() over(partition by item_id,name order by case when priority='T' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
from tablename 
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER` provides one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_Id, name ORDER BY priority DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    item_Id,
    name,
    value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The strategy here is to assign a row number sequence value to each item/department group of records (which would be either one or two records).  True priority records get assigned a sequence value of 1, unless not present, in which case priority false records would be assigned 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I use group by to achieve below result?

Yes, you can use `group by`:

```
select item_id, name,
       coalesce(max(case when priority = 'T' then value end),
                max(value)
               ) as value
from t
group by item_id, name;
```

There are other ways to express the logic.  `row_number()` is one of them.  As is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where priority = 'T' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.item_id = t.item_id and
                        t2.name = t.name and
                        t2.priority = 'T'
                 );
```